# Closing a file without using using

Tags: c#, idisposable, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a class which reads data from one file stream and writes to another. I am concerned about closing the streams after the processing has finished in closeFiles().

How would you handle the possibility that the dispose of one stream may throw an exception stopping the dispose of the other stream from being called.?

Should I be calling close and dispose on the streams or just one?

What happens if I catch any errors from the stream disposes and then continue with moving and deleting of the files as shown in lastOperation()?

In a perfect world I'd like to use a using statement in a c++ style initialisation list but I'm pretty sure that's not possible in c#.

**EDIT** : thanks for the quick responses guys. So what I should be doing is deriving from IDisposable and then change the constructor and add the two disposing methods like this?:

```
    ~FileProcessor()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                sw.Flush();
            }
            closeFiles();
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

This is basically what I'm doing:

```
class FileProcessor
{
    private string in_filename;
    private string out_filename;
    private StreamReader sr;
    private StreamWriter sw;
    bool filesOpen = false;

    public FileProcessor(string filename)
    {
        in_filename = filename; 
        out_filename = filename + ".out";
        openFiles();
    }

    ~FileProcessor()
    {
        closeFiles();
    }

    private void openFiles()
    {
        sr = new StreamReader(in_filename);
        sw = new StreamWriter(out_filename);
        filesOpen = true;
    }

    private void closeFiles()
    {
        if (filesOpen)
        {
            sr.Close();
            sw.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
            sw.Dispose();
            filesOpen = false;
        }
    }

    /* various functions to read, process and write to the files */

    public void lastOperation()
    {
        closeFiles();
        File.Delete( in_filename );
        Directory.Move(out_filename, outdir + out_filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Re the Edit: You should still loose the destructor. And check sr,sw individually.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I saw your addition about individual checking after I made the edit, it's already in my code :). I got the 'advice' to keep the destructor from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(VS.71).aspx which suggests "Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code. This destructor will run only if the Dispose method does not get called." I read this as the destructor won't be expensive if the object is disposed but that there are circumstances where the destructor will be needed... I might start another question about this specifically.

Comment: Patrick, the class in that MSDN example has an unmanaged resource. You only have managed resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your FileProcessor class should not have a destructor. It is of no use but it is expensive.

It should have a `Dispose()` (and implement the IDisposable interface) to call closeFiles().

And like @marcelo answered, Stream.Dispose() should not throw. You can rely on this for BCL classes.

But you should check each Reader/Writer for null, in case the first one opened but the second one failed:

```
if (sr != null) sr.Dispose();
if (sw != null) sw.Dispose();
```

Your `filesOpen` can't cover both.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a good practise to have your class implements `IDisposable` interface if you are using IDisposable object inside it.

Then, you should make sure that, in your `Dispose()` implementation, don't throw exceptions. If every object you dispose makes this guarantee, your client will be safe.

Answer (score 2):

Dispose methods should never throw exceptions. There's even a code analysis tool [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386039.aspx) for this.

Comment: Dispose methods should throw exceptions if and only if they are unable to satisfy the expected post-conditions with regard to the objects affected by the object being disposed.  Dispose methods which fail are bad, but dispose methods that fail silently are worse.

Comment: @supercat: In my experience, things that fail on their way out only make things worse by throwing exceptions. The best policy, I've found, is to log an error, report it, etc. and then continue unwinding. Perhaps I'm at odds with industry norms here. I'm more of a C++ guy, and in C++, throwing an exception from a destructor is basically anathema. Is the advice different for C#? Do you have a link I can peruse?

Comment: Qualifier: I understand that Dispose is not a destructor, but to me the principle of operation is pretty much the same, and so the hazards of throwing an exception in Dispose are pretty much the same as for the destructor. Perhaps I'm off the mark on this too, but again it would be nice to know what the industry norm is.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Basically, one should whenever possible design disposers so they don't fail unless something is very seriously wrong.  If the code which uses a disposer is properly written, the failure of one disposer shouldn't prevent others from unwinding, but since there's no way for a disposer to know how its caller is written, throwing from a disposer carries some risk.  The problem is that a still-living object's state got corrupted and one doesn't throw, there may not be a good way to signal the problem and show where it happened.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: One approach might be to have the longer-lived object have a 'corrupt' flag, along with an Exception object and stack trace indicating how it became corrupt; if an attempt is made to use the longer-lived object after it has become corrupt, that attempt could throw an exception with the corrupting exception as the InnerException.  I've not seen that done, but it might be a nice pattern.  Unfortunately, I know of no nice way to make the InnerException's stack trace match what it was when original exception occurred.

Comment: @supercat: Thanks for your thoughts. This seems analogous to what I do in C++: if I absolutely have to signal the fault (due to corruption of an object or the process), I would invoke `*(int*)0 = 0;` and crash the process. Since this is not an option in .Net (even in unsafe mode, I'm guessing it would just trigger an exception), you `throw new TheSkyIsFalling();` instead, or just allow thrown exceptions to propagate. Am I reading you right?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Basically.  Sometimes throwing a new exception may be appropriate if the outside code may be expecting to catch an exception on the assumption that the dispose put things back to a good state.  Having a "more severe" exception to indicate the dispose failed may be helpful.  Too bad everything inherits from Exception, but not from any other usable base.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, `using` does exist. The object provided to the using statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's resources.

If your StreamReader and StreamWriter implement IDisposable, you can put them in a using block, and they will be disposed of cleanly when you have finished with them.

```
using(var sr = new StreamReader(in_filename)) {
    // Perform reader actions
}
// Reader will now be disposed.
```

Comment: But I'm opening the stream in the constructor and need to keep it open for the lifetime of the class...

Comment: Then put the class in a using block.

Comment: Put the class in a using block? That is plain and simple a wrong advice, since it can't be done. How would you expect that kind of code to function?

Comment: @Øyvind: that depend hot the FilesProcessor is going to be used. It could be feasible. Or not.