# Using destructor/finaliser expensive?

Tags: c#, destructor, idisposable, finalizer

I'm busy getting confused about non-deterministic destruction. In an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302712/closing-a-file-without-using-using) I got the advice that destructors/finalisers (which I assume are the same thing in c#, i.e. the function called ~classname()) are expensive and not required. But looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(VS.71).aspx) example a destructor is used and from the comment sounds like it may be vital. Anyone got some advice about how this all fits together and should I remove the destructor from my code?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only include a finalizer if you absolutely *have* to run some cleanup at some point, whether it's performed explicitly or not. In such cases you should always have an explicit way of performing clean-up in a timely manner anyway, and that should suppress finalization anyway, so that "good" clients don't see any performance penalty.

You would normally only need a finalizer if you have a direct handle to unmanaged resources - if you only have a reference to *another* class which has a handle on the resource (e.g. `FileStream`) then you should leave it to the other class to have a finalizer.

With the advent of [`SafeHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) in .NET 2.0, situations where it's worth writing your own finalizer are [very rare indeed](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=86c71425-57bc-4fcb-b34b-3262812f12cf).

The performance penalty of finalizers is that they make your objects live for longer than they need to: in the first GC cycle where they're otherwise considered eligible for collection, they get put on the finalizer queue - and bumped up to the next generation just like any other object which survives a GC cycle. The finalizer will then run in another thread (at some point) and only *then* will they be eligible to really be collected. So instead of (say) getting collected in the first gen1 collection, they live on past that until the next *gen2* collection, which may be considerably later.

Comment: Yes, a pity that even the Fx4 version of that link does not mention SafeHandle.

Comment: A bigger performance penalty is that any objects <i>referenced</i> by a finalizable object will be non-collectable for another generation, as will any objects referenced by those, or any objects referenced by those, etc.  If an object references, directly or indirectly, objects which won't be needed during finalization, the object shouldn't have a finalizer.  Instead, the things which are actually needed for finalization should be encapsulated in their own finalizable class, and the bigger object should hold a reference to that.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, implementing a destructor is useful in on case: when it is not guaranteed, that client code will close all the resources(file streams, db connections and so on) properly. So, if client code will fail to do so, you will have code, which will close it, which is better than just left the resources open.

Comment: unless those resources have their own destructor, as all your examples do.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the full Disposable pattern when you are dealing with an unmanaged resource directly. And then it is up to your calling code to make sure the destructor is (almost) never used.

When dealing with managed resources (= indirect ownership of unmanaged resources), the destructor is useless:

```
class FileWrapper
{
    private FileStream fs;  // managed resource

    ~FileWrapper()
    {
         if (fs != null) 
           fs.Dispose();   // fs is already on the GC finalizer queue
    }
}
```

Whenever a FileWrapper object is being collected by the GC, it is certain that the fs object is in the same batch. So the call to fs.Dispose() is useless, only testing the correct (allowing multiple calls) behaviour of the FileStream.Dispose().

The only useful destructor here is the one in FileStream.

Comment: @LukeH: No, it is safe. It could have been Disposed but not collected. Type-safety still holds in a destructor.  And there is no race condition either.